# How do you select all records in a 24-hour time period and summarize the data in SQL?

Tags: sql-server, date, datetime

I have a SQL 2014 table containing hourly records of gas meter consumption.  Each record contains the DATETIME date along with the meter identifier and the associated gas consumption for the past hour.  The problem I am having is we need to know the total daily consumption beginning with the 10:00 am record thru the 9:00 am record of the following day.  This time period is considered our "Gas Day".  My ending result is to have each gas meter listed with a summary of gas consumption for each "Gas Day".  Listed below is a sample of my data:

## MeterID    LogDate    Consumption

1007643 2015-10-30 01:00:00:00   19
1007643 2015-10-30 02:00:00:00   27
1007643 2015-10-30 03:00:00:00  26
1007643 2015-10-30 04:00:00:00  27
1007643 2015-10-30 05:00:00:00  26
1007643 2015-10-30 06:00:00:00  26
1007643 2015-10-30 07:00:00:00  38
1007643 2015-10-30 08:00:00:00  50
1007643 2015-10-30 09:00:00:00  35
1007643 2015-10-30 10:00:00:00  45
1007643 2015-10-30 11:00:00:00  46
1007643 2015-10-30 12:00:00:00  44
1007643 2015-10-30 13:00:00:00  38
1007643 2015-10-30 14:00:00:00  45
1007643 2015-10-30 15:00:00:00  35
1007643 2015-10-30 16:00:00:00  47
1007643 2015-10-30 17:00:00:00  44
1007643 2015-10-30 18:00:00:00  40
1007643 2015-10-30 19:00:00:00  27
1007643 2015-10-30 20:00:00:00  48
1007643 2015-10-30 21:00:00:00  48
1007643 2015-10-30 22:00:00:00  48
1007643 2015-10-30 23:00:00:00  28
1007643 2015-10-31 00:00:00:00  6
1007643 2015-10-31 01:00:00:00  6
1007643 2015-10-31 02:00:00:00  6
1007643 2015-10-31 03:00:00:00  7
1007643 2015-10-31 04:00:00:00  6
1007643 2015-10-31 05:00:00:00  6
1007643 2015-10-31 06:00:00:00  7
1007643 2015-10-31 07:00:00:00  6
1007643 2015-10-31 08:00:00:00  6
1007643 2015-10-31 09:00:00:00  6
1007643 2015-10-31 10:00:00:00  15
1007643 2015-10-31 11:00:00:00  96
1007643 2015-10-31 12:00:00:00  45

The ending result for the example above, which contains more records than needed for one (1) "Gas Day" is to begin adding the Consumption column beginning with the 2015-10-30 10:00:00:00 record and ending with the 2015-10-31 09:00:00:00 record.  The query would return the following:

1007643 2015-10-31 645

I am sure this is very simple, but I am new to SQL and would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To find the totals for each 'gas day' for each Meter ID, you could do something like this:

```
SELECT [MeterID], MAX(CONVERT(DATE, [LogDate])), SUM([Consumption])
FROM tblName
GROUP BY [MeterID], DATEDIFF(hh,'1900-01-01 10:00:00', [LogDate])/24
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the name of the table is GAS, the date field is DT, and the field you want to sum is AMT, it would be something like this, if you wanted to get the total for yesterday (pseudo-SQL):

```
SELECT SUM(AMT) FROM GAS WHERE DT BETWEEN ('2015-12-15 00:10:00') AND ('2015-12-16 09:00:00')
```

Comment: This would work if I only wanted to get one day in my query.  I need all records for each day for each meter summarized.  Thanks!